# Magento: How to prevent magento subdomain to show in google search index

Tags: magento-1.7, seo, google-analytics, index

I have moved my Magento files from sub-domain "/magento" to root folder successfully, and I created and generated the google sitemap from admin catalog > google sitemap, and I added "Disallow: /magento/" to robots.txt file, but I still see "www.mydomain.com/magento/‎" shows when I do seach in google by writing "site:www.mydomain.com"

I tried also to remove robots.txt from root and I went to System > Configuration > General > Design, and at Default Robots I choose "INDEX, FOLLOW"

Still I see "www.mydomain.com/magento/‎" appear in google search

I hope someone can guide me with a solution it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .htaccess file, you would use this line to 301 redirect correctly:

```
RedirectPermanent /magento/ http://www.Your_Domain.com/
```

That will 301 redirect everything that was in the /magento directory to your main domain without the sub-directory. It will properly keep all the URLs intact that were in the magento directory. Nice and clean.

Comment: After doing your redirection I got 503 error "service not available" on both front end and back end, I had to google the problem and I found that I have to delete maintenance.flag file from root directory to get back everything, it was hardest 5 minutes I felt

Comment: I did your solution again and it works without any problem, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear ALL  indexed urls in Google stays there for minimum 90 days. Second in your root's `.htaccess` file just add `Disallow: /magento/` to prevent search engines to crawl or index that directly any further. Finally just to be safe add a `301 Redirect` to redirect all who ever land up on `/magento/` directory to your store's home page.

Ensure that under no circumstances anyone can access /magento/ directory, if they do they are redirected to store's home page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should allow /magento/ in robots.txt because Google shouldn't index this pages and it shouldn't know about that your pages moved to different url. Next step - you should re-check your url configuration(it may be rewritten on other scopes), flush cache, reindex URL rewrites and re-generate sitemap.xml file and check it for correct url's. Than you should make 401 redirect from yourdomain.com/magento/something.html to yourdomain.com/something.html. You can make it via .htaccess(if you using Apache) or server configuration if you using nginx. Than you should try go to [https://www.google.com/search?q=site:yourdomain.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3ayourdomain.com) and try go to few links, if it's redirecting correct - great. If no - you should re-check your redirect configuraion. After all changes you should re-upload sitemap.xml in your Google Webmaster tools.

Comment: Thanks Igor for the detailed answer, just need to know how to do 401 redirection what I have done is that: `
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/magento
    RewriteRule ^(.*)magento$ http://cabas-durables.fr/$1 [R=401,L]
`
I think this is wrong redirection